# Repair damaged Python3.2 installation (Ubuntu)

Tags: python, apt-get

I stupidly removed the `subprocess.py` module from `/usr/lib/python3.2` so I tried to fix this by executing the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

But I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 33, in <module>  
    from subprocess import PIPE, Popen ImportError:
    No module named subprocess dpkg:
    error processing python3 (--configure):
    subprocess   installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1 dpkg:
    dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-gobject:  
    python3-gobject depends on python3 (>= 3.2); however:
    Package python3 is not configured yet.  python3-gobject depends on python3 (<<
3.3); however:
    Package python3 is not configured yet. dpkg: error processing python3-gobject (--configure):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
    Errors were encountered while processing:
    python3  python3-gobject E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried uninstalling Python 3 and then installing it again?

```
sudo apt-get remove python3
sudo apt-get install python3
```

or maybe

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install python3
```

If this does not work, just grab subprocess.py from the python repository and copy it to the right directory. For example, for Python 3.2.2, navigate with your browser to:

http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/137e45f15c0b/Lib/subprocess.py

and the click in "raw" (left column) to download the file.

For other versions, just go to:

http://hg.python.org/cpython/tags

Pick your version, then click on browse (left column), then Lib (from the folders list), then "subprocess.py" and then "raw" (left column) to download the file.

Comment: I've tried it ,but does't work. the console shows the same error

Comment: thanks a lot, when I cp the raw file to where it belongs to, problem solved.

Comment: After spending 2 days with same issue, finally `sudo apt-get --reinstall install python3` solved issue.