# Unmet dependencies when trying to install python and Django on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, dependency-management, apt

I am new in python/django and following [How To Install the Django Web Framework on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-django-web-framework-on-ubuntu-14-04) and "Global Install through pip(section)" for installation,

when I run `apt-get install python-pip`, I get below error

```
aagyat@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install python-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-orca : Depends: python3-brlapi but it is not going to be installed
 gnome-sudoku : Depends: python3-gi-cairo (>= 2.90.1) but it is not going to be installed
 onboard : Depends: python3-gi-cairo but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: onboard-data (>= 0.99.0~alpha1~tr1531) but it is not going to be installed
 python-pip : Depends: python-pip-whl (= 1.5.4-1ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: python-dev-all (>= 2.6) but it is not installable
 python3-commandnotfound : Depends: python3-gdbm but it is not going to be installed
 python3-pip : Depends: python-pip-whl (= 1.5.4-1ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: python3-dev (>= 3.2) but it is not going to be installed
 python3-software-properties : Depends: unattended-upgrades but it is not going to be installed
 usb-creator-common : Depends: python3-debian but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

and even running `sudo apt-get -f install python-pip` getting same error in console.

How can I fix this, your help will be highly appreciated.

And when I run only `sudo apt-get -f install` it gives following errors

```
dpkg: error processing package usb-creator-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of usb-creator-gtk:
 usb-creator-gtk depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 usb-creator-gtk depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 usb-creator-gtk depends on usb-creator-common (= 0.2.56.3ubuntu0.1); however:
  Package usb-creator-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package usb-creator-gtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-minimal
 python3
 language-selector-common
 python3-xkit
 ubuntu-drivers-common
 python3-gdbm:amd64
 python3-commandnotfound
 apturl-common
 python3-pycurl
 unattended-upgrades
 python3-software-properties
 software-properties-common
 software-properties-gtk
 apturl
 gedit
 python3-xdg
 python3-speechd
 python3-pyatspi
 python3-brlapi
 python3-louis
 gnome-orca
 python3-cairo
 python3-gi-cairo
 gnome-sudoku
 language-selector-gnome
 onboard
 python3-chardet
 python3-lxml
 python3-plainbox
 python3-six
 python3-urllib3
 python3-requests
 python3-pyparsing
 python3-checkbox-support
 python3-checkbox-ng
 python3-colorama
 python3-debian
 python3-distlib
 python3-feedparser
 python3-html5lib
 python3-httplib2
 python3-markupsafe
 python3-mako
 python3-setuptools
 python3-pip
 python3-uno
 python3-wheel
 rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist
 rhythmbox-plugins
 usb-creator-common
 usb-creator-gtk
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential` try this one.

Comment: I did and see same error. @RahulKP

Comment: `sudo apt-get update` and try once more.

Comment: Tried and didnot work out, same error @RahulKP

Comment: I tried and I edited my question with response, please have a look. @AnttiHaapala

Answer (score 3):

Finally solved with below command and  for more information follow link

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install python3
```

[Repair damaged Python3.2 installation (Ubuntu)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446863/repair-damaged-python3-2-installation-ubuntu)

Comment: Hmm, how did you break your Python 3?

Comment: I was doing some R&D few days ago and I think by mistake I break Python.